# How use mutt to manage /var/spool/mail/user

Tags: email, mutt

I've just installed [apticron](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apticron) to get mails as *available update notifications*. Now I was wondering if there was a way to set up [mutt](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mutt) to manage my mails from `/var/spool/mail/daedalus`?

I'm on Debian Jessie, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up the mailbox(es) to use in mutt via `~/.muttrc`.

It would be something like this (see the manpage for `muttrc` for the full details):

```
set folder=/var/spool/mail
set mbox=+daedalus
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not need any extra files. Great for peeking into the mail spool.

```
mutt -f /var/spool/mail/daedalus
```